# What is the time format string for EET/EEST in python?

Tags: python, strptime

I am a python beginner and I have the timestap as following

```
x:"Mon 20 Feb 2012 09:44:22 AM EET"
x:"Wed 27 Aug 2014 09:36:48 AM EEST"
```

I am wondering what is the format string for EET/EEST in python? I have already come up with : `datetime.strptime(x, '%a %d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %p ??')`.
What should I put instead of ??

Thank you

Comment: check out this link http://opensourcehacker.com/2008/06/30/relativity-of-time-shortcomings-in-python-datetime-and-workaround/

Comment: Look at [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this formatting works with UTC, but not other time zones (have tried EST, CST, IST)

So just write this like.

```
>>timestamp = datetime.strptime('10/23/2019 6:02:05 PM EEST', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p EEST')

>>2019-10-23 06:02:05
```

This ignores the time zone and produces a time zone naive datetime, which will not error out (unless a time zone other than EST is input), but will also not pass the timestamp correctly because it is not passing the time zone